# When using Xcode and swift, I can't get the type of value while typing

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm using Xcode13.2, but from a long time ago, the values's type can't be displayed when using swift, but when using objective-c there is no issue.

when define String type value, typing string and from the list there is no message for the type of string
[image: Using Swift]

in Objective-C, there is a `NSString *string` that I can understand the type for string.
[image: Using Objective-C]

is there any way to get the type of a value while typing in swift?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, did you compile the code first?

Comment: Even after compilation, the problem did't gone,

Comment: my co-worker using Xcode13.1 also did not reproduce, next I try to reinstall Xcode and cleanup temporary files...  For supplement my Mac is m1 Mac mini and  co-worker 's Mac is intel mac

Comment: I think we can all agree that Xcode's code completion feature is pretty poor. But I don't see how Stack Overflow can be expected to do anything about it.